# Cannot access Libraries after upgrade to SP1

Tags: 2010, list, libraries

I just installed SP1 & now I am unable to access any library on my site collection.

The error I get is as follows:

> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 2110f768-aaf9-44ab-859d-2a62194a8302

**However, Lists are working perfectly.**

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: So, what does Correlation ID: 2110f768-aaf9-44ab-859d-2a62194a8302 say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ULS View](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) in order to audit your Correlation ID

Also, this reference source will help you: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=353

Comment: Even though that might be a part of the solution this is more a comment than an answer. Please consider adding comments for things like this, for reasons of clarity and comprehensibility.

Answer (score 1):

Verify you have all the SharePoint Server Site Collection and Site Features activated that deal with document libraries.  I had the same issue until I activated those features!

Hope this helps!